# Neo4j Procedure throwing error

Tags: neo4j, procedures

I'm just starting to learn how to write procedures. My simple proof of concept still isn't passing muster when Neo4j starts up. Here is the code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.logging.Log;
import org.neo4j.procedure.Context;
import org.neo4j.procedure.Mode;
import org.neo4j.procedure.Procedure;

public class Procedures {

@Context
public GraphDatabaseService db;

@Context
public Log log;

@Procedure( name = "create_user", mode = Mode.WRITE )
public Stream<Create_user_response> create_user() {

    ArrayList<Create_user_response> myList = new ArrayList<>();

    Create_user_response res1 = new Create_user_response();
    res1.out = 1;
    myList.add(res1);

    Stream<Create_user_response> myStream = myList.stream();

    return myStream;        

}

}
```

Here's my Create_user_response class:

```
public class Create_user_response {
    public int out;
}
```

When Neo4j starts up it complains that my procedure needs to return a stream of records. I'm new to streams so I must be doing something wrong but just can't figure it out.

I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had a bad dependency,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-harness</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

wasn't working. I found it in a tutorial and its in Maven, but for some reason I must not have been doing something correctly with it.